# How do I remove HTML elements with specific attribute value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to remove `a` tags with specific attribute value from a `div` tag.

This is for example:

```
<div id='testdiv'>
    <a dir='hello' href='#' ></a>
    <a dir='how' href='#' ></a>
    <a dir='which' href='#' ></a>
</div>
<input type='button' id='btn' />
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
   if($("#testdiv").find("a[dir='hello']").length == 1)
   {
       $("#testdiv").remove("a[dir=hello]");
   }
}
```

But its not working. What change shall I need to do with my jQuery?

Comment: Whats the question ? this code is not working as intended ?

Comment: `dir` isn't a valid attribute for an anchor. If you need to use custom attributes, check out [`html5 data attributes`](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/)

Comment: I hope this can help you understand the functionality better http://jsfiddle.net/cVb5h/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$("a[dir=hello]").remove();
```

Here's the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Answer (score 1):

It's working:

```
$(function(){
        $('#btn').click(function(){
                if($("#testdiv").find("a[dir='hello']").length=='1'){
                    $("#testdiv").find("a[dir='hello']").remove();
                }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
   $("#testdiv").remove("a[dir='hello']");
})
```

- You need no `if`.
- You forgot the quotes in the `remove` statement.
- You forgot the last `)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`$('a[dir="hello"]').remove`